# Laravel , crear un array para luego insertarlo en BD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, php5

estoy con laravel y mi idea es crear un array y dentro poner distintos elementos que es otro array.

Intento  recrear esta estructura

```
exercices = [
0 => [
    name=> "test1",
    peso   => "100,
    category_id => 1
],
1 => [
    name => "test2",
    peso   => "200,
    category_id => 10
],
```

]

Para ello tengo este código , primero hago un bucle con un for y luego recojo del modelo Exercises uno de cada uno e intento ponerlos en el array

```
        $exercises = [];

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $exercises [] = Exercises::all()->where('category_id',1)->take(1);
            $exercises [] = Exercises::all()->where('category_id',10)->take(1);
         }

        foreach ($exercises as $ex) {
           dump($ex->category_id,$ex->name);
        }
```

El código me funciona hasta que llego al "foreach" donde no me encuentra category_id , creo que me "falta" un nivel , por eso mi pregunta si cuando relleno el array lo hago bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que estas intentando acceder a la propiedad name de un arreglo
debes hacerlo asi:

```
    foreach ($exercises as $k => $ex) {
       echo $exercises[$k]["name"];
       echo $exercises[$k]["category_id"];
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias  ,era eso

Answer (score 0):

He probado lo que me has comentado y al hacer un dump de $exercises[$k] obtengo este resultado , me estoy dejando un nivel?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]